# Can Windows Steady State be used as a virtual machine undo feature

Tags: steadystate

Can I install Steady State, then install a bunch of stuff to try, then revert back, then uninstall Steady State?

Kind of like a virtual machine undo.  I don't want to do this in a VM because I want the full machine power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just configure SteadyState to wipe all changes on reboot. Install desired software, muck around, break what you want. When you're done just reboot, uninstall SteadyState, and you're good as new.

Comment: I would add that disk imaging would be neater and less hassle. It's a pain to commit changes and update Windows when using SteadyState.

Comment: Except disk imaging takes quite a while. I'd go the virtualization route and take snapshots.

Comment: As the OP wants 'full machine power', bootable VHDs would be a great solution, although this requires Win7/2008 R2, and in my experience it takes a bit of fiddling to manipulate drive letters to how I want.  It is an very useful feature though, and I no longer dual-boot when it comes to Windows.